# TKinter - How do you use variables in hex to color widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, hex

I'm trying to set a frame's background color a hex value which I've stored in a variable. I did something wrong and it's giving me this error "unknown color name 'hex_value'." What am I doing wrong?

```
hex_value = "#f35123"
root = Tk()
top_frame = Frame(root, bg="hex_value")
top_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because you passed in the *string* "hex_value". Instead of the variable containing the string you want. Remove the `"`

Comment: Oh god, what was I thinking?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you want the *content* of the variable?!

```
hex_value = "#f35123"
root = Tk()
top_frame = Frame(root, bg=hex_value)
top_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
root.mainloop()
```